# how to changing year date picker value range to 1320:1396

Tags: php, date, datetime, datepicker

can you please help.how can I change date picker value change to 1320 to 1396?

here that part code:

(right now year range is 1902:2017 , but i want change this range to 1320:1396)

```
for ( $i = date('Y', time()-60*60*24); $i > 1901; $i-- ) {
                    $html .= sprintf( '<option value="%1$s" %2$s>%3$s</option>', (int) $i, selected( $year, $i, false ), (int) $i );
                }
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the function `selected()` compares `$year` to `$i` and if so, adds `selected` to the option.

In this case I don't think you'll have to do anything fancy with date. I think you can just transform the for loop to this:

```
for ($i = 1396; $i >= 1320; $i--) {
```

I'm not sure how it fits into the rest of your code, but this loops i from 1396 to 1320.

Comment: i got white page when changing to this. .  

someone told me use this js.  but i dont know how can i add this js.

if (parseInt($('select.bxcft-birthdate-year').children(':last').val()) !== 1940) {
            $('select.bxcft-birthdate-year').children('option:not(:first)').remove();
            for ( var i = 2030; i >= 1940; i-=1 ) {
                $("<option></option>").attr('value', i).text(i).appendTo('select.bxcft-birthdate-year');
            }
        }